# ViewStub layout vertical bias doesn't move the viewstub down

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout with a ViewStub inside it. I have added constraints to the viewStub. but, I wanted to move it down a bit and I tried to use vertical bias but it doesn't move at all. any idea why?

here is my Viewstub

```
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/no_data_viewstub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout="@layout/no_data_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.71000004" />
```

here is the layout that I use in the views tub

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
        android:text="@string/oops"
        android:textColor="@color/azure"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nodata" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView38"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_data"
        android:textColor="@color/error_massage"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was a simple error. view stub height can not be match constraint.

in order to change the bias, it needs to have a hight of wrap content.